# Firebase console to Google console

Tags: firebase, google-places-api, firebase-console, google-cloud-console

I have project setup in Firebase console. Firstly I implement Firebase Cloud Messaging and now I want to integrate Google Places API but I don't know how. If I had created the project in Google console then I can do that but I had created in Firebase console.

Firebase console allow us to import project from Google console but is there a reverse way?

Comment: The project you make are already synced to other googles consoles.
Log in to your console.developers.google.com and there you find your project

Answer (score 4):

I was also confused about this.  Initially I thought I had to create a Google Cloud Platform project for a Google Firebase project.  But then I figured out Google Firebase automatically created a Google Cloud Platform project for me.

How to find the Google Cloud Platform project associated with a Google Firebase project:

1. Take note of the name of your Google Firebase project from https://console.firebase.google.com
2. Log into https://console.cloud.google.com
3. At the top of the screen, find the project selector (it's to the right of the "Google Cloud Platform" logo)
4. On the "Select a project" window, click the "ALL" tab and there should be a Google Cloud Project by the same name as your Google Firebase project you noted above

What initially confused me was the "Select a project" window defaults to a "RECENT" tab.  But when you've just created the project from Firebase's console, it doesn't show up in the RECENT tab of Google Cloud Platform's console.

Comment: God bless you for the "click the ALL tab". I couldn't find mine without your answer.

Answer (score 1):

All Firebase projects are also Google Cloud Platform projects. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com to see the project you created at the Firebase console, but from the perspective of Google Cloud services.

You can think of Firebase as adding extra services to a Cloud project that you normally can't see in the Cloud console.